# jQuery slider ui -- dynamically set starting value from HTML element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to read the value of my slider from a DIV element's title (which may be the issue). That is pushed into the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myslider5").slider({
        min: -1000,
        max: 1000,
        value: parseInt($(this).attr("title")),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
              // more actions
        }
    });
```

I think I get NaN error. Any clues?

Comment: how are the div's titles like?

Comment: `<div class="myslider5" id="id-1" title="-791">-791</div>`

Comment: @publicRavi - Are you setting the min/max? the default range is 0-100, which -791 wouldn't fall in.

Comment: @Nick C Yes, I am. Just wanted to show the important lines :)

Comment: @publicRavi - Is there more than one `.myslider5`?

Comment: @Nick C Yes, their number dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's more than one of this class, you'll need to iterate over them and create the sliders using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), like this:

```
$(".myslider5").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value: parseInt($(this).attr("title")),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
              // more actions
        },
        min: -1000,
        max: 1000
    });
});
```

[Here's an example of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnDCc/), otherwise you'll get the value from the title of the first of these in the set, you can see the [`.attr()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or details:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: @Nick C I had tried that, but held on to the `$(".myslider5").slider({`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `$(this)` is not taking exact value so try to give value as:

```
$(".myslider5").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value: parseInt($(".DiVID").attr("title")),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
              // ...
              // more actions
              // ...
        },
        min: -1000,
        max: 1000
    });
});
```